# Is it plausible there will be an established form of European English in the future?

Tags: english, dialects, creoles

What is more probable:

A) there will be an established form of European English in the future that will differ slightly from British or American English?

Or

B) the English dialects in the world will become closer due to the digital media?

Comment: What makes you think there isn't already a European English?

Comment: Why do you think either of those is possible? They're certainly not the only options, nor the most likely.

Comment: Or (C) Europe will abandon English and adopt German, or Russian, or Chinese.